# What makes clipping with starred graphics object and its dual produce different result?

Tags: pstricks

Based on the following taken from `pstricks.tex`,

```
\def\solid@star{%
  \if@star
    \pslinewidth=\z@
    \psdoublelinefalse
    \def\pslinestyle{none}%
    \def\psk@fillstyle{\psfs@solid}%
    \let\psfillcolor\pslinecolor
  \fi}
```

starred object

```
\xxx*[linecolor=<color>]
```

is similar to

```
\xxx[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=<color>,linestyle=none,linewidth=0]
```

However, this similarity is no longer held when we use them as the clipping path. In the following example, a red solid rectangle will be clipped by a circle.

The first clipping uses the starred version `\pscircle*[linecolor=blue]` and produces a blue circle. But the second clipping uses its dual `\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linestyle=none,linewidth=0]` and produces a red circle. So the second clipping produces the expected result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](4,4)
    \psclip{\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](2,2){1}}
        \psframe*[linecolor=red](4,4)
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](4,4)
    \psclip{\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linestyle=none,linewidth=0](2,2){1}}
        \psframe*[linecolor=red](4,4)
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

What makes this difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, both `\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](2,2){1}`
and `\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linestyle=none,linewidth=0](2,2){1}`
result in the same closed blue circle.
However, the order of corresponding `postscript` commands is somehow different.
Command `\pscircle`
...

```
0 360 arc closepath gsave 0 0 1  setrgbcolor
1. .setopacityalpha fill  grestore clip
```

builds the circular path first, saves the current graphic state with `gsave`,
sets sets current `color` and `alpha`, fills the circle 
and restores the graphic state with `grestore` just before the `clip`,
thus the color/filling commands are filtered out from the `clipping path`.

on the other hand, command `\pscircle*` generates different `postscript` sequence:

...

```
0 0 1  setrgbcolor 56.90549 56.90549 28.45274
1. .setopacityalpha  SD  clip
```

where `SD` stands for `0 360 arc fill`, thus the color/filling commands stay in the clipping path and apparently, they are applied after clipping.

Comment: important is only when `stroke` is called. However, it has nothing to do with a correct clipping path.

Comment: @Herbert: Compare `postscript` image
`newpath 0 200 moveto 200 200 lineto 100 380 lineto closepath gsave 1 0 0 setrgbcolor fill grestore gsave clip grestore 0 0 1 setrgbcolor fill`
with the same image, but without first `gsave`/`grestore` pair.

Answer (score 3):

a clipping *path* is a *closed curve* and *not* a filled area. Using a star version for the clipping path produces an unexpected behaviour